# Remote Site Domain Controller Failure

Tags: active-directory, domain-controller

We have a remote office with defined AD Site and local DC that has failed. Clients cannot authenticate. We have a private WAN to HQ but I'm unclear of change needed or impact. Do I just move the subnet to the HQ site? What will that do to the DC object which we hope to have back up in 2-3 days? Is this the way to go?

Help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Configure the clients to use one or more of the other Domain Controllers for DNS so that they can find a suitable Domain Controller. There's no reason they shouldn't be able to log on even if the Domain Controller in their site is unavailable unless they're only using the failed Domain Controller for DNS.